# Matrix normal, then is the same true for the fundamental system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, dynamical-systems, fundamental-solution

Let $A : [0,T]\to\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be a matrix function such that each $A(t)$ is normal, i.e., $A(t)^TA(t) = A(t)A(t)^T$ for all $t\in [0,T]$. Now, consider the ODE system $\dot x(t) = A(t)x(t)$. We know that there exists a $n\times n$ fundamental matrix function $\Phi(t)$ such that the columns of $\Phi$ are linearly independent solutions of the ODE, that is, $\dot\Phi(t) = A(t)\Phi(t)$ for $t\in [0,T]$ and fixing the value $\Phi(0)$ also fixes the fundamental system.

My question:

> If $A$ is normal as above, does the same hold for the solution of
> $\dot\Phi(t) = A(t)\Phi(t)$ with $\Phi(0) = I_n$?

For constant $A$ this is true as the solution is given by $\Phi(t) = e^{tA}$, which is easily seen to be normal for each $t$. It's also true when $A(t)$ is diagonal for each $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true.  Let $$A(t)=\begin{cases}\begin{bmatrix}0&\log{(2)}\\\log{(2)}&0\end{bmatrix} & 0\leq t<1 \\
\begin{bmatrix}0&\frac{\pi}{4}\\-\frac{\pi}{4}&0\end{bmatrix} & t\geq1\end{cases}$$ Then $\Phi(0)=I_2$, $\Phi(1)=\frac{1}{4}\begin{bmatrix}5&3\\3&5\end{bmatrix}$ (so far so good) but $\Phi(2)=2\sqrt{2}\begin{bmatrix}4&4\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}$, which is not normal.

To see how I got this, note that this sort of phenomenon is generic: assuming $A$ constant, on a finite interval, the solution $\Phi$ is continuous in $A$.  So if we can approximate $A$ in the uniform norm, then $\Phi$ will depend continuous on the approximation (in, e.g., the uniform norm on $(\Phi,\dot{\Phi})$).   In particular, we can approximate $A$ by a piecewise-constant function.

So suppose $A$ attains value $M_1$ on $[0,t_1)$ and $M_2$ on $[t_1,t_2)$, etc.  Then $$\Phi(t_2)=e^{M_2t_2}e^{M_1t_1}\Phi(0)$$  Now, if $A$ is very nice, and $M_1$ and $M_2$ commute, then we can reduce this to $e^{M_2t_2+M_1t_1}\Phi(0)$.  If they don't commute, this value is off...but not by much; c.f. the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula.  In any case, this is a real danger: a sum of normal matrices need not be normal!  A classic example is $$\begin{bmatrix}0&a+b\\a-b&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&a\\a&0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0&b\\-b&0\end{bmatrix}$$  The remainder is just messing around with the constants.

**Edit**: the OP has asked for a $C^1$ example.  The key idea is that the solution varies continuously in $A$, as measured in the $L^1$ norm of $A$.  More precisely: let $B$ match $A$ on $[0,1-\epsilon]$ and $[1+\epsilon,2]$, and quadratically interpolate between.  Say $\Phi_A$ and $\Phi_B$ solve the obvious systems; clearly $\|A-B\|$, $\|\Phi_A\|$, and $\|\Phi_B\|$ are all bounded (in norm) on $[0,1+\epsilon]$ by, say, $M$.  Then $$\|\Phi_B(1+\epsilon)-\Phi_A(1+\epsilon)\|\leq M((1+\epsilon)-(1-\epsilon))\sup_{s\in(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)}{\|A(s)-B(s)\|}\leq2M\epsilon$$  On $[1+\epsilon,2]$, we have again $A=B$, so that $$\frac{d}{dt}(\Phi_A-\Phi_B)=A(\Phi_A-\Phi_B)$$  Taking norms and solving, on $[1+\epsilon,2]$, that $2M\epsilon$-sized difference grows by a constant factor of $e^{\|A\|(1-\epsilon)}$.  But $$\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}{2M\epsilon e^{\|A\|(1-\epsilon)}}\to0$$ and there are no normal matrices near $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}4&4\\-1&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.  (To see that last claim, note that $XX^{\mathsf{T}}-X^{\mathsf{T}}X$ is continuous in $X$.)

Comment: Ok, thank you! That's a statement. But what if $A$ is $C^1$?

Comment: @amsmath: There is a $C^1$ function $B$ that approximates my $A$ in the uniform norm by at most $\delta$: this follows from, e.g., the Weierstrass approximation theorem.  But since $A\mapsto(\Phi|_{[0,2]},\dot{\Phi}_{[0,2]})$, considered as a function from $C([0,2])\to C([0,2])^2$, is continuous, solving the same system with $B$ replacing $A$ will give a $\Phi$ that is at-most $\epsilon$ away.  And there are no normal matrices near $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}4&4\\-1&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

Comment: I'd like to see such a matrix function that uniformly approximates your $A$, which performs a clear jump at $t=1$.

Comment: @amsmath: I wrote that too quickly; you're right, there isn't one. A better response is too long for a comment, so I'll edit it into the answer.